# Fixed header issue iOS

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, uiwebview

Having a small issue with iOS devices. I have a fixed header but when scrolling down if the user clicked an input link while the header is over it then the header gets stuck at that position till the keyboard is hidden.

As soon as I hide the keyboard the header resets. Is this a known problem with iOS devices and is there a known solution for this ?

I want to keep the fixed header due to better usability and making it relative would be the last option.

[image: iOS error]

Thank you.

Comment: can you upload a screenshot?

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot but I think there are some permissions conflicting and not displaying it properly. I did find an answer though. Posted it below :)

Answer (score 2):

I found simple solution for this:

```
if ( /iPhone|iPod|iPad/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    $(document).on('focus', 'input, textarea', function()
    {
         $('header').css("position", 'absolute');
         $('footer').css("position", 'absolute');
    });

    $(document).on('blur', 'input, textarea', function()
    {
         $('header').css("position", 'fixed');
         $('footer').css("position", 'fixed');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which seems like a good fix. I have posted the link below for anyone who might run into this problem :)

http://dansajin.com/2012/12/07/fix-position-fixed/

Cheers.